# how to programmatically align a label to an x, y coordinate

Tags: ios, alignment, label, coordinates

below are some other properties of the label. obviously nstextalignmentleft is not what i'm going for. having trouble understanding where to enter coordinates.

```
self.lblTimer = [[UILabel alloc] init];
self.lblTimer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
self.lblTimer.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
self.lblTimer.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];
self.lblTimer.textColor = [UIColor redColor];`self.lblTimer = [[UILabel alloc] init];
```

Comment: What is it that you're trying to do? `textAlignment` can only be set to left, right, center, justified, and natural. Are you looking to create an offset between the edge of the label and the text?

Comment: The label is a timer that counts up. I'm just trying to place it in the bottom left of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding what `textAlignment` does. This simply controls the alignment within the label, not on the screen. If you want to position the label on screen you must change its `frame` property:

```
self.lblTimer.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,width,height);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you've set `self.lblTimer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `NO` I am guessing you want to use [Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html) and if so, I highly recommend taking a look at [Masonry](https://github.com/Masonry/Masonry).

An alternative is to set the `frame` property on the label with requires a `CGRect` where you give it the x and y coordinates as well as the width and height.